# Bullet Shooting problem (bullet stops moving after shooting another)

Tags: python, pygame

So I am working on Asteroids clone project. My problem in this project is shooting. So when I shoot the bullet it goes in right direction based on angle of the player but when I shoot another bullet previous one stops moving.

Here is the bullet class :

```
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, rocket):
        self.bullets = []
        self.angle = 0
        self.bullet = pygame.Rect(rocket.posX - 30, rocket.posY - 20, 30, 30)
    
    def shoot(self, rocket):
        self.angle = rocket.angle
        self.bullet = pygame.Rect(rocket.posX - 30, rocket.posY - 20, 30, 30)
        self.bullets.append(self.bullet)
        

    def update(self):
        self.angle = self.angle % 360
        self.xDir = math.radians(self.angle)
        self.yDir = math.radians(self.angle)
        self.bullet.x += math.cos(self.xDir) * 2.0
        self.bullet.y -= math.sin(self.yDir) * 2.0
        
    def drawToScreen(self,screen):
        for self.bullet in self.bullets:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), self.bullet)
```

and here is the game loop (ignore some comments):

```
 while run:
        
        #angle = angle % 360

        dt = clock.tick(FPS)/1000
        
        #xDir = math.radians(angle)
        #yDir = math.radians(angle)
        #randRect.x += math.cos(xDir) * 2.0
        #randRect.y -= math.sin(yDir) * 2.0
    
        rocket.update()
        bullet.update()
        
        
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False 
            
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet.shoot(rocket)

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        rocket.movement(keys_pressed, dt)
                          
        drawToWindow(screen, rocket, bullet)

        #pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), randRect)       
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)
    
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not actually moving each bullet in self.update(), just the most recent bullet that was created in self.shoot(). Try something like:

```
def update(self):
    self.angle = self.angle % 360
    self.xDir = math.radians(self.angle)
    self.yDir = math.radians(self.angle)
    for bullet in self.bullets:
        bullet.x += math.cos(self.xDir) * 2.0
        bullet.y -= math.sin(self.yDir) * 2.0
```

Also, I noticed you're doing "for self.bullet in self.bullets" in the self.drawToScreen() method, and that seems like that might cause issues (if it isn't already). Try doing just:

```
for bullet in self.bullets:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), bullet)
```